# Finding an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose k is infinite. Then the irreducible algebraic subsets of $A^2(k)$
are: $A^2(k)$,$\emptyset$, points, and irreducible plane curves $V(F)$, where $F$ is an irreducible polynomial and $V(F)$ is infinite. Here I am looking for an example where $F$ is irreducible but $V(F)$ is finite so that it is not an irreducible algebraic set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.  The only point where it vanishes is $(0,0)$, and you can show $F$ is irreducible by the same method as in my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615296/showing-a-polynomial-irreducible).  If you want $V(F)$ to not be irreducible, you could take $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$, and then $V(F)=\emptyset$.  If you don't like considering the empty set to not be irreducible, you could take $F(x,y)=x^2(x-1)^2+y^2$.

Comment: I am sorry I should have said V(F) is finite so that V(F) is not an irreducible algebraic set. I am editing.

Comment: My second example works for that--the empty set is not irreducible.

Comment: I would rather strongly argue that any definition by which the empty set is irreducible is an incorrect definition of irreducible (it's very similar to the fact that you shouldn't consider $1$ to be a prime number).  In any case, I've added another example, which should look familiar.